# How to compress an .APK file say by Winrar(.rar) and then convert it back to .APK?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, compression, rar

As you all know a disadvantage of Xamarin Forms apps is their huge size. Though I went through different scenarios for reducing app size such as Linking and using Proguard, my Android APK size is still so high(about 30 MB). The thing is when I compressed this apk by Winrar the size got to about 11 MB. I renamed this compressed .rar file to .apk file but when I tried to install this file I got the message: "There was a problem parsing the package".

So my question is is there any mechanism to leverage the compression of a tool like winrar for an APK file so that it could be installed on any Android device?

Comment: If you are intended to publish it on the google play store, for example, be warned that it has an automatic compression mechanism that's handled by the `Play` app on client devices. You may think about check the option `Generate on package per selected ABI` too.

Comment: Yes I already enabled that option. Though another option for further reducing app size is to enable Linking All option (SDK and User Assemblies) and configuring proguard such that App won't crash. But as that requires a time-consuming analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this isn't that easy. 
During the packaging process, your app archive will be hashed. If you rar it or do any other tampering with the archive, the resulting app archive will have a different hash than the one it was built with. This will result in your apk invalidating itself on install due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to unpack it then on the device again. You can't just go and rename a file and expect it to work, the binary structure is completely different.

You will need the user to download an app that is capable of unpacking a .rar (or whatever format you decide on) and learn the user to extract the APK file from there and then install it. The you do need to take into account is that the user needs to be a bit tech savvy to be able to do this and in some cases might even need more rights on a device than is usual. As far as I know there is no delivery mechanism that does this for you.

If you ask me, 30 MB isn't that much and the trouble to go through all this isn't worth the few megabytes you shaved off. If you look at the average apps in the store they are easily bigger than that.

Comment: Surely I wanted our ordinary users to be able to install the app through store, in a standard manner.
Hmm, I just wondered if an APK could be compressed this much by a third-party tool like Winrar, maybe same thing could be performed via development tools or Android OS themselves.
Thanks anyway.