# Why does Xamarin build an apk with very little compression? And how do I improve this?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, compression

So it's my first time to build a Xamarin APK file, and I noticed that the compression is very lacking compared to native Android APK! For example:

**Xamarin Android**

- Xamarin APK Size: `30MB`
- Extracted contents of the APK: `60MB`
- Extracted contents compressed into ZIP file: `20MB`

**Native Android (*same app: same assets and about the same code/logic*)**

- Native APK Size: `20MB`
- Extracted contents of the APK: `59MB`
- Extracted contents compressed into ZIP file: `19MB`

Notice how the native APK's compression is about that of the ZIP file.

Now, how do I improve Xamarin APK's compression? Can I just zip the contents then change the extension?

Thank you.

Comment: `Now, how do I improve Xamarin APK's compression? Can I just zip the contents then change the extension?`, well an APK is already an archive. I don't think zipping it works. Also, why don't you try and see what happens when you do that instead of asking?

Comment: What I mean is: extract the APK, zip the resulting files, then change the extension from .zip to .apk? Will that work in the Playstore?

Comment: an APK is a special zip file created by Google. Also, why do you ask instead of try it yourself?

Comment: I wanted to achieve the same thing:[How to compress· an . APK file· say· by Winrar( . rar) and then convert· it back to . APK ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111983/how-to-compress-an-apk-file-say-by-winrar-rar-and-then-convert-it-back-to-ap)

Comment: Did you read through the documentation regarding why packages are slightly larger?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/app-package-size

Answer (score 0):

You can't never get a smaller APK file using Xamarin. Using Xamarin implies that you must use .NET libraries that are bigger in size than their counterpart in Java.

On release mode, you can generate one APK per ABI, set the linker behaviour to Link SDK Assembly only and select only the ABIs you want to distribute your app. This way you can save a few KBs.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]